# How can i get @rErr / Output Parameter value in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, output-parameter

I create a SQL stored procedure

```sql
create proc p1
(
@name1 nvarchar(50),
@rErr int OUTPUT
)
as
begin Transaction
    insert into test (name1)
    values (@name1)
    if  @name1 = 'n100'
        Begin
            Rollback Transaction
            Set @rErr=50001
            Return @rErr
        End
commit Transaction
```

How can I get the `@rErr` value in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing output parameters is a little awkward; you need to add them to the parameters collection in the usual way, with with a `.Direction` of `Output`. Then you can read the `.Value` of the parameter object *after* executing the method. However: it is much easier to use `select` and process it as a result. Note that `return` values can be done in a similar way, but with the appropriate `.Direction`. The fact that you both `output` *and* `return` it, in this case, makes it even more fun... I'd just use the `output` part, personally. Or ... throw an exception (`raiserrror`).

Something like:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "p1";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var name = cmd.CreateParameter();
    name.ParameterName = "@name1";
    name.Value = "abc"; // etc
    cmd.Parameters.Add(name);

    var err = cmd.CreateParameter();
    err.ParameterName = "@rErr";
    err.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(err);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (err.Value is int i)
    {
        // error i happened
    }
}
```

However: if you'd just used:

```
raiserror (50001, 16, 1) -- severity needs to be at least 16 here; typically = 16
```

or (in more recent SQL Server versions):

```
throw 50001, 'oops', 1
```

you can get a similar result much more easily; this will result in an `Exception` direction from the ADO.NET layer.

(note that you should add the custom error message formally to `sysmessages` when using `raiserror` - `throw` doesn't require that step)

If you used the `throw` (or `raiserror`) approach, and removed the `output` parameter, this entire piece of code could become, with some help from [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/):

```
conn.Execute("p1", new { name1 = "abc" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

which is a *lot* easier to get right!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need transaction for a single insert, you can refactor your SP like following. To return the code as output parameter, you can simply use `RETURN(50001)`

```
CREATE PROC P1 (@name1 NVARCHAR(50), 
                @rErr  INT output) 
AS 
    IF @name1 <> 'n100' 
      BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO test(name1) 
          VALUES      (@name1) 

          RETURN(0) 
      END 

    RETURN(50001)
```